# Is it possible to roll back to a previous customization of Genesis?

Tags: genesis-theme-framework

Excuse my ignorant question, but couldn't find anything about this anywhere.

I did some changes on a Genesis based site. The site was set to **display last posts** (rather than static page) and I used the *customizer* to make changes. Now, the site owner told me she doesn't want the changes, and to roll back to what it was.

I exported the site before anything, so I guess I can recover from that. But in my experience, every time I have used the **WP generated Export backup** it duplicated a lot of things, specially menu items.

I would like to know if it's possible to roll back in some way, without importing the file. I only need 3 or 4 lines of text and importing will cause more trouble than writing them (if I had those lines, of course).

If not, is there a way to check on the import file for the way the customization was at the moment I backed it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find that https://wordpress.org/plugins/customize-snapshots/ may be useful in retrieving a snapshot, or at least being able to take a snapshot before you do work like this again in the future.